# How to retrieve data from remote MySQL database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to store data in Android **SQLite Database** from a remote MySQL database.
In this purpose I do not like to use json or xml.

Answer (score 0):

In this purpose at first you have to know how to connect to a remote MySQL database from android application. After connecting to the **MySQL Database** then you can load the data in your internal **SQLite** database.